# javascript to jQuery or vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can just about struggle through with jquery, javascript less so.

I have a small function written in javascript, but I need to change the selectors. I wouldn't have any problem in doing this in jquery, but I do in js.

I need help either: converting my selector to its js equivalent, or converting the function in its entirety to jquery (as its only 4 lines of code).

```
function findNextTabStop() {

    // This is the current selector
    var universe = document.querySelectorAll("input");

    // In jQuery, the NEW selector would look like this
    $universe = $(this).closest(".form").find(".input-wrapper input, .input-wrapper select, .input-wrapper textarea");

    var list = Array.prototype.filter.call(universe,
        function (item) {
            return item.tabIndex >= "0"
        });

    var index = list.indexOf(this);

    return list[index + 1] || list[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Also share some sample HTML

Comment: It's part of a form - the form contains various types of input, but each one is always inside a DIV (.input-wrapper). When enter is pressed whilst focusing on an input, this function is triggered - it looks up all inputs, finds the index of the current input, the gets the next, where focus is eventually applied.

Comment: And now you wish to uniform the way you access elements. Right? Why not pass `$universe` in filter or even try to use `$.filter`

Comment: That's the point Rajesj, I've done very little with js and nothing with arrays, so, I don't know the right way to go about it - either in js or jquery.

Comment: Can you try and create a Fiddle or at least share your HTML. Its difficult to visualize and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging and testing, this is what I've come up with

```
function findNextTabStop() {

    $el = $(this).closest(".input-step").find(inputs);
    var index = $el.index(this);
    return $el[index + 1] || $el[0];
}
```